# lodash - How to convert a nested object into a unique array?

Tags: arrays, coffeescript, underscore.js, lodash

I have this array with a nested "`atts`" object in an array of `items`.

```
baseData = [
    {
        id: 123123
        name: "Some Product"
        atts: {
            lowfreqrange: 100,
            package: 'connector',
            amplifier: 'narrowband'
        }
    },

    {
        id: 5556652
        name: "Some Second Product"
        atts: {
            lowfreqrange: 50,
            package: 'drop-in',
            amplifier: 'LNA'
        }
    },

    {
        id: 5465456
        name: "Some 2 Product"
        atts: {
            lowfreqrange: 100,
            package: 'connector',
            amplifier: 'narrowband'
        }
    }
]
```

and I'd like the output to be:

```
[
    lowfreqrange: [100, 50]
    amplifier: ['LNA', 'narrowband']
    package: ['connector', 'drop-in']
]
```

Is there a quick way to handle this with lodash other than manual looping? I have this but would like to see how I could do it with lodash, mostly for educational purposes:

```
for item in baseData
    atts = item.atts

    for k, v of atts
        result[k] = [] unless result[k]
        result[k].push v
```

Comment: I think your manual loop solution above is incorrect. The expected output provided above is suggests that each array must be unique, since there are two `100` lowfreqrange, two `connector` package and two `narrowband` amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the map and reduce functions like so.

```
result = _(baseData).map((item) ->
  item.atts
).reduce((result, item) ->
  result.lowfreqrange.push item.lowfreqrange
  result.package.push item.package
  result.amplifier.push item.amplifier
  result
,
  lowfreqrange: []
  package: []
  amplifier: []
).valueOf()
```

See it in action (in vanilla JS) here: http://jsbin.com/siniku/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know much about coffeescript so I'll write my solution in plain javascript. You can solve this by plucking each `atts` key value.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/t8adVn6TeUqSWntqlXF7?p=catalogue)**

```
var result = _.reduce(['lowfreqrange', 'package', 'amplifier'], 
  function(object, key) {
    object[key] = _(baseData).pluck(['atts', key]).uniq().value();
    return object;
  }, {});
```

Alternatively, if you're not certain with the number of `atts` keys or you simply don't want to hard code them then you can simply fetch them all first and then apply the solution above.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fAigEAaH7h6eWiFYciIU?p=preview)**

```
var result = _(baseData).pluck('atts').map(_.keys).flatten().uniq()
  .reduce(function(object, key) {
    object[key] = _(baseData).pluck(['atts', key]).uniq().value();
    return object;
  }, {});
```